# Prevent Outlook from wrapping text in messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

How can I prevent Outlook from wrapping the text in my messages?

For example, if I save a draft of an email, when I open it up again, line breaks have been inserted.

I have options set to UTF-8.

[image]

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: I also use Outlook 2013, but have never heard about this issue. Does it affect all of your mails? Are all lines wrapped? To which length?

Comment: Are you OK with using HTML emails? You could try replacing all spaces in your HTML email with non-breaking spaces. This should leave the lines exactly as formatted.

Comment: Is word your default editor for outlook?  Also have your tried RTF?

Answer (score 2):

file->Options-> Mail

in the 'Message format' block:
Automatically warp text at character->132

Default is 76 and is quite alright

you cannot remove it or make it longer than 132... (Outlook mail Format)

Answer (score 1):

I am correct in stating that text wrapping at character 132 is a bit misleading.

Outlook appears to wrap at a character column based on some relativity to a fixed font size but this does not always relate to text in different fonts.
e.g. I put in some output from SQL into an email which had a record length of 1049 and it did not wrap at the 132nd column of my data. I was using Consolas font and font size of 8. When I switched to a font size of 4, the whole line displayed without any wrapping.

Character wrapping at 132 would make more sense if I was outputting and reading my mail from on an old LA120 dot matrix printer which had a physical cline length limit of 132 characters. The Outlook application has no physical limit on line length.

Comment: That was using the HTML mail format as well.