# Enable text wrapping in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

How do you enable text wrapping in Outlook? Outlook version below.

In my Outlook settings it says that text should be wrapped at 76 characters. But when typing an e-mail this never happens.

**What I get**

[image]

**What I would expect**

[image]

**Outlook options**

[image]

**Outlook version**

[image]

Comment: Well, how did you get the expected image?

Comment: did you see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1426310/345317)?

Comment: @WasifHasan putting the enters myself in the text? FYI, I just put them randomly not at the 76 characters. It just displays sort of the behavior I expect.

Comment: @RegEdit yes, but I do not understand what he trying to say there.

Comment: Nor do I completely :) but it seems to me the salient points applicable to your case too are (1) he reminds us that Outlook, by expressing line length as a number of columns, is actually using an obsolescent concept more applicable to fixed fonts than the proportionally spaced fonts that are now ubiquitous, (2) Outlook therefore has to infer an "effective line length" from whatever value is used for the setting in question, taking into account the font face and size, and (3) Outlook appears not to be very good at that.

Comment: Also I have seen in at least one version of Outlook (not my current 365 version, though it may be in your 2002 version) another setting in a different section that controls whether Outlook applies your wrap setting *in the editor window*.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same issue as you?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/30538565-0bb0-4036-af3e-33a710e62173/outlook-doesnt-wrap-the-text?forum=outlook

As mentioned in this thread, The wrapping only applies to Plain Text messages that you receive. It is not a composing option nor does it apply to already received messages.